# SqlException Try-Catch with vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, exception

I'm trying to wrap my head around `Try-Catch` statements in vb.net. I am trying to handle a SQL exception error that occurs, but I'm not sure what to do with it? The particular method that contains the code sample below is also expecting a return value.

```
Try
    Dim records As DataRecordCollection = Sql Insert SP call
Catch sqlEx As SqlException
    Select Case sqlEx.Number
        Case 547
        *****What goes here?*****
        Case Else
            Throw
    End Select
End Try
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if SQLException number 547 occurs?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the options are? To not crash the program I guess.

Comment: If you can recover..recover. It its fatal send a message and terminate gracefully

Comment: You said that this code is part of a function that returns a value, so I suppose you could return a value that indicates that an error occurred. You might also log the error somewhere, or display a message to the user. It's up to you.

Comment: "To not crash the program" is sort of a rough one.  Will the program still function correctly without the `records` object?  If not, it might be best to simply display some sort of message to the end user stating that the operation didn't succeed, if so, you might be okay to simply allow it to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put whatever you want there. We can't give you the answer to this question, because it could be *anything*. It could also be *nothing*; you don't have to put anything at all in that place, though it's usually poor practice to just swallow an exception like that.

The point is what you put there depends *entirely* on your application. You might make a log entry, or clean up the error to show something nicer to the user, or put other code there to recover or try again, or even all of the above. Whatever you want. But we can't know what you want to do. That's up to you and your design specification.

Also, you can simplify this code using a conditional exception:

```
Try
     Dim records As DataRecordCollection = Sql Insert SP call
Catch sqlEx As SqlException When sqlEx.Number = 547
     // Put whatever you want here
End Try
```

Finally, in my experience the best option is usually to *skip the Try/Catch block at this level entirely.*

If you have a well-designed application, your database access is abstracted away into it's own class, assembly, namespace, or some combination thereof, that is separate from the UI or Business layer. My experience is that handling these exceptions in the database code is not as helpful as allowing the exception to bubble up to a higher level of abstraction. You'll be better positioned to deal with it there. That's kind of what Try/Catch is all about... that exceptions can be caught at the level that is most appropriate to that kind of exception.

This is especially true when *you don't even know what you want to do*. If you don't have a plan to handle an exception, then don't handle it. Ditch the Try/Catch block and let the exception bubble up to a higher level where maybe someone else has a better strategy for it.

Comment: Thank you @Joel Coehoorn for the reply. I obviously need to read up on this topic, but your post was a good start for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft SQL server stores the error messages in the database so you can query it in your server:

```
select * from sys.messages where message_id = 427 and language_id = 1033
```

When I run it on my Sql Server 2016 Express, I got the following result:

```
Could not load the definition for constraint ID %d in database ID %d. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG to verify the integrity of the database.
```

I suggest you to debug the error message not only the number and you will get some additional information about your problem. So please log the error message too, write that here and with that we will be able to help you.

Thank you,
Morzel